# Sumar elementos de una array y dejar uno

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo

```
var cargos = [{
        "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
        "Referencia": "IM",
        "Precio": 73710
    }, {
        "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
        "Referencia": "IM",
        "Precio": 32856

    }, {
        "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
        "Referencia": "IS",
        "Precio": 220970
    }, {
        "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
        "Referencia": "IS",
        "Precio": 98568
    }];
```

Lo que necesito realizar es sumar los que son IM y sumar los que son IS, y me debería de quedar un arreglo

```
var cargos = [{
            "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
            "Referencia": "IM",
            "Precio": 106566
        },  {
            "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
            "Referencia": "IS",
            "Precio": 319538
    }];
```

Alguna idea de como realizarlo en **js**

Comment: Adjunta código de lo que hayas intentado, ¿has buscado alguna información? Echale un vistazo a [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

utiliza las funciones **filter** y **map** de `javascript`, seria:

```
var im = cargos.filter(function(datos){
             return datos.Referencia == "IM"
         })
//en la variable im tendrás todos los IM , por si los necesitas luego
// ahora sumar los precios
var preciosIm=0;
    im.map(function(elemento){
       preciosIm += elemento.Precio  
     })

//para los IS seria de igual manera pero cambiando las búsquedas y las variables

   var iS = cargos.filter(function(datos){
             return datos.Referencia == "IS"
         })
//en la variable iS tendrás todos los IS , por si los necesitas luego
// ahora sumar los precios

var preciosIs=0;
    iS.map(function(elemento){
       preciosIs += elemento.Precio  
     })
```

Tendrás la variable **im** con todos los datos que sean IM, la **iS** con todos los IS , y tendrás **preciosIm** y **preciosIs** con la suma de los precios de cada cual.

Si necesitas llevarlo todo a un solo arreglo dirias:

```
//redefines el arreglo cargos
cargos = [{
        "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
        "Referencia": "IM",
        "Precio": preciosIm
    },  {
        "TipoProducto": "Cargo",
        "Referencia": "IS",
        "Precio": preciosIs
}];
```